# Indented multi-tiered lists (and headings), with org-indent-mode?

Tags: org-mode, indentation

I am new to Emacs, using it to structure text/ideas. After enabling word wrap from the menu and doing `M-x org-indent-mode`, I would like my document to look like this (the returns in the middle of sentences should be soft returns that adapt to the width of the window):

```
* The idea
  * Example One
    Curabitur suscipit et dui quis placerat. Nunc aliquam posuere elit,
    maximus velit elementum non. Cras accumsan ex velit, eu semper arcu
    fermentum vel.
    + Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin
      gravida tincidunt magna, mattis mattis massa maximus sed. Donec
      varius vestibulum nibh imperdiet tristique. Vestibulum sit amet
      lacinia nibh.
      - Integer eu dapibus nulla.
      - Nam varius risus dolor, eu ultricies lorem ultrices et. Nulla
        bibendum lectus dui, eget iaculis velit posuere sed. Donec
        imperdiet felis dui, eget sodales sem feugiat nec.
```

Whereas now it looks like:

```
* The idea
  * Example One
    Curabitur suscipit et dui quis placerat. Nunc aliquam posuere elit,
    maximus velit elementum non. Cras accumsan ex velit, eu semper arcu
    fermentum vel.
    + Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin
    gravida tincidunt magna, mattis mattis massa maximus sed. Donec
    varius vestibulum nibh imperdiet tristique. Vestibulum sit amet
    lacinia nibh.
      - Integer eu dapibus nulla.
      - Nam varius risus dolor, eu ultricies lorem ultrices et. Nulla
    bibendum lectus dui, eget iaculis velit posuere sed. Donec
    imperdiet felis dui, eget sodales sem feugiat nec.
```

... because the indentation always reverts to that used below the last *-marked header. The - and + list bullets (and their manually given indentation) are not considered in the automatic indentation of the wrapped text.

Using headers throughout would be messy/clumsy/overkill since the text blocks at the + and - marks are not titles.

Is there a way? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that in org-indent-mode, but in regular org-mode it works like you want.

Comment: Hm, thanks but I don't see that? What does happen: if I type Return then Tab after a paragraph, the cursor jumps to the position where I might want to put a bullet one further level down. So it recognizes bullet points. But it does not handle the indentation of the wrapped text as I would like. Plus: outside of org-indent-mode, the headers are not automatically indented :/. (Maybe it depends on the version? I'm using Emacs 23.4.1 with Org-mode 6.33x.)

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. Instead of hitting return then tab, try hitting `C-j` (`org-return-indent`). To fix your current bullets, try joining the lines (so that each bullet takes up only one line) and then hitting `M-q` to fill paragraph.

Comment: Let's see... `C-j` seems to do the same as Return then Tab, but `M-q` does indeed do the paragraph indentation right - didn't know about that! It still doesn't seem to be a full solution, since (1) unlike with org-indent-mode there is no indentation for headers, and (2) `M-q` seems to introduce hard returns (at least so it seems when I copy a paragraph and paste it into a different program). I should mention in the question that that isn't the intention. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to update your Org-mode a more recent version.  6.33 is very old.  It works fine for me with `org-indent-mode` and soft word wrap using Emacs 24.4.1 and Org-mode 8.2.10 - see screenshot below.

I have customised the `org-indent` face to be underlined in gray so you can see the visual prefix that is added to each line.

[image: screenshot illustrating]

Comment: You're right - thank you! I might have tried a newer version earlier, if I hadn't been having trouble lately with updating and installing packages in my Mint 16. I now found a solution for that [here](https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/#disqus_thread) (a simple repository address change substituting `old-releases` for `archive` and `security`) and then installed Emacs24.2.1 with Org 7.8.11. And it works. Thanks again. I'm indented to you ;-) Btw, whence the dotted box instead of a star?

Comment: The dotted box is actually a die showing the number one.  I use `org-bullets` from https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets and my `org-bullets-bullet-list` is set to `("⚀" "⚁" "⚂" "⚃" "⚄" "⚅" "♧" "♡" "♢" "♤" "♣" "♥" "♦" "♠")`